# Run a new regex over the contents of another matched group

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

hope some kind soul would shed some light on this one!

I am using a translation program that supports regex but I do not know the exact flavour yet. I want my regex to work first so I can ask for their support later.

This regex will extract the contents of text enclosed between " ". There are many peculiarities but I will keep it "simple" for now.

1- Even the text inside " " has a few " that should be kept.

2- only the text sections betweeen STRINGTABLE and END should have their contents extracted the way explained above. For instance:

3- Ignore lines that have words starting with # as they are commented variables.

```
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    IDS_STR_VAR_DEFINE_TIP  "Connect Current Cell to a Defined Variable"
    IDS_STR_DEFINE          "Define"
    #IDS_STR_DEFINE_TIP      "Display Defined Variable Wizard"
    #IDS_STR_UNLINK          "Unlink"
    IDS_STR_UNLINK_TIP      "Remove link to "" a Defined Variable"
    IDS_STR_DELETE          "Delete"
END
BLA BLA BLA "do not want captured"
```

Main limitation: The translation program will only take the **1st returning group** to create its projects.

Now I did some extensive research in this site and other online resources and came up with 2 regexes that works independently but what I actually need is to apply the 1st regex to the matched results of the 2nd regex.

Another thing: My translation program only accepts 1 expression per file so this has to be done in 1 regex!

1st regex:

```
([^"](?:"(.*)")[^"]*$)
```

Extracts only the text enclosed between " " without including ". Works great in https://regex101.com/ with PCRE and /gm modifiers set. Except that it still takes the lines which have variables starting with #. I don't know how to get rid of them. Maybe you know?

2nd regex

```
(STRINGTABLE[\S\s]*?^END)
```

This one works too - it can match all text between STRINGTABLE and END including lines.

I tried all sorts of back-tracking into capturing groups but I think I am missing something. Regexes like:

```
(STRINGTABLE[\S\s]*?^END)(?<1>[^"](?:"(.*)")[^"]*$)

(STRINGTABLE[\S\s]*?^END)(\1[^"](?:"(.*)")[^"]*$)

(STRINGTABLE[\S\s]*?^END)\1([^"](?:"(.*)")[^"]*$)
```

Are not working at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you only want the lines `"Connect Current Cell to a Defined Variable"
             "Define" "Remove link to "" a Defined Variable" "Delete"` ?

Comment: What do you mean by _Extracts only the text enclosed between " " without including "_ ? As far as I checked your regex `([^"](?:"(.*)")[^"]*$)` matched whole text from **Connect . . . . captured**

Comment: As best as I can tell, I do not believe that what you want to do can be accomplished in a single regex (with one possible exception).  The reason is that you want to restrict between STRINGTABLE and END.  As such, the entire contents of that block of text will be a single match, so any expression with this restriction will not be able to evaluate the "IDS_" lines as individual separate matches using a global search, which is what you'd need to extract submatches for each line.  The exception I mentioned is if you always had six "IDS_" lines to evaluate, which I know is not the case.

Comment: I mean I do not want to include the " " delimiters in my match group. For example: i do not want "Define" -- I only want Define without any " "

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st regex can be like this:

`\s+\w+\s+([^"](?:"(.*)")[^"]*$)`

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fD6xK6/1)**</kbd>

or try this

```
^\s+\w+\s+"(.*)"$
```

Explanation:
`^\s+` Start with multiple spaces
`\w+` Text
`\s+` multiple spaces
`"(.*)"$` Capture any between "" until end of line

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kT5tE2/1)**</kbd>

Comment: ▲ for `^\s+\w+\s+"(.*)"$`. I was wondering how to evade that `#`.

Comment: `^\s+#\w+\s+"(.*)"$` Will include that `#`. Just remove `#` to evade that `#` : D

Comment: Yes yes ! I got that from your answer.

Comment: Thanks, you figured how to remove the # lines!